# How to calculate /get the UBER value from S.M.A.R.T measurements in SSDs

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, benchmark, smart

**UBER** is a metric for the rate of occurrence of data errors, equal to the number of data errors per bits read over the entire lifetime of an **SSD**.
Mathematically:
[image]

The numerator is the total count of data errors detected over the full **TBW** rating.

How can i get this value from S.M.A.R.T attributes?

[image]

Or is there a better way to calculate the UBER value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the **UBER** (unrecoverable bit rate error) can be calculated based on the raw value of the attribute *#ID 187*, **reported_Uncorrect**. 
Several manufacturers tend to use different names for this attribute and that what create some confusion.